# Multithreading – known similarity solution

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I am looking for a known solution (as **producer-consumer problem**) for this situation .

---

In my case there are two options:

- **link to image**,
- **text file with links** to images and links to other text files (with other links).

I'm trying to create a multi-threading downloader in **C++** (on unix) using **posix mutex** and **posix semaphore**.

Application has link to the first text file.

---

1. Threads sleep (semaphore = 0).
2. Main thread downloads first text file.
3. Parse for other links -- put links in some queue (semaphore += links_count --> other threads wake up).
4. Other threads produce other links.

What with main thread?
How to check other threads -- finish state?

---

With use finite queue there can be deadlock: text file contains many links (queue as full with other text files). No text file can be finished.

---

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No, I will try to create small utility for backup images. The text file is generated by our websites.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is still kind of a producer/consumer problem but your consumers are also producers. Some ways to deal with the problem:

- Do not limit your queue size. Simply fail when your process runs out of memory. Not very elegant but will probably work in 99.99% of all download scenarios (assuming 100 bytes per download link on average and about 2GB available memory you would have to store more than 20 million links in your queue before running out of memory).
- Split your producer and consumer by using the hard drive as buffer. Download files into a temporary folder. Have a thread watch that folder for new files. Once a new file appears, parse it and put the items in the consumer queue. Once the file is finished parsing put it into the final download location. This way you are only limited by disk space. This way your producer (parser) is a different thread than your consumers (downloader).

**Edit**

You can wait on your worker threads with [`pthread_join`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks :-). And what is the moment to terminate application?

Comment: @Nanik: See my updated answer - `pthread_join` is your friend.